# Setting JMenuItem accelerator text, not just action

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem

For my swing application a `JMenuItem` has the accelerator set like this:

```
JMenuItem numFieldsMI = new JMenuItem("Set Number of Fields");
numFieldsMI.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_3,
         ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK+ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK));
```

This, when the GUI is intitialized, makes the text next to the menu item read "Ctrl+Shift+3" but of course the intent is that the text be "Ctrl+#". How can I do this?

Comment: I think `ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK+ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK` should be `ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK | ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK`...

Comment: I had a play around with `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMBER_SIGN, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK)` and `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMBER_SIGN, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK | ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK)` and neither would trigger the menu's `ActionListener`, whereas `KeyEvent.VK_3, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK | ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK)` did work, although it did display `Ctrl+Shift+3` ... so, you can have it display what you want or work, your choice

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
numFieldsMI.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_3,
         ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK+ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK));
```

to

```
numFieldsMI.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_3,
         ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK ***|*** ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK));
```